# Extracting utcOffset from an ISO String with Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Using moment.js, I'm attempting to extract the offset from an ISO date string so I can use the offset later when formatting an epoch timestamp to ensure the conversion of the timestamp is in the same timezone.

Even though the offset in the string is -0400, the result is always 0;

```
var currentTime = "2015-03-18T16:10:00.001-0400";
var utcOffset = moment(currentTime).utcOffset(); // 0
```

I've attempted to use parseZone() as well without success.  Is there a way to extract -0400 from the string so I can use it while formatting another time?

Thanks for the help!
KC

Comment: Definitely working... https://jsfiddle.net/0de50bfp/

Comment: That's odd.  I'm not getting that same answer.  But I'll go back and review the code and see whats going on.  Thanks for the link to jsfiddle to see it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The correct way to extract the offset is indeed with `parseZone`

```
var currentTime = "2015-03-18T16:10:00.001-0400";
var utcOffset = moment.parseZone(currentTime).utcOffset();
```

This should result in `-240`, which means 240 minutes behind UTC, which is the same as the `-0400` in the input string.  If you wanted the string form, instead of `utcOffset()` you could use `.format('Z')` for `"-04:00"` or `.format('ZZ')` for `"-0400"`.

The form you gave in the question just uses the computer's local time zone.  So it is currently UTC+00:00 in your time zone (or wherever the code is running), that would explain why you would get a zero.  You have to use `parseZone` to retain the offset of the input string.

Also - your use case is a bit worrying.  Remember, an *offset* is not the same thing as a *time zone*.  A time zone can change its offset at different points in time.  Many time zones do this to accommodate daylight saving time.  If you pick an offset off of one timestamp and apply it to another, you don't have any guarantees that the offset is correct for the new timestamp.

As an example, consider the US Eastern time zone, which just changed from UTC-05:00 to UTC-04:00 when daylight saving time took effect on March 8th, 2015. If you took a value like the one you provided, and applied it to a date of March 1st, you would be placing it into the Atlantic time zone instead of the Eastern time zone.

Comment: This is an excellent explanation, Matt.  Good point about the offset vs time zone.  In my case, everything will be applied using the same day, except in odd cases where the time will run up against the end of the day.  In that situation, especially around daylight savings, I would have the wrong time applied and will evaluate other options.  Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: This worked for me moment().utcOffset(date).utcOffset()

Comment: @Nipun - yes, that will work as well.  It is slightly less correct, as the moment object you create will not be the same one you provide in `date`, but since you discard it anyway you will get the same result.

Comment: No Matt with the solution that you posted I was not getting the correct result. Try with this site. It will not give the correct timezone.

Comment: Downvoted, the jsFiddle provided in @MattJohnson answer does NOT extract the offset from currentTime, it actually just outputs the current offset of the local machine. (By coincidence his local machine might actually have a timezone with offset -0400)
The solution by @Nipun works as expected and returns `-240` regardless of the timezone of the local machine.

Comment: @Su-AuHwang Nope, I'm in Pacific Time, which would return `-420` if it were the current offset. [Here's proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvrIO.png).  The key point I was making is that `moment.parseZone` specifically is designed to set the `Moment` object it produces to the fixed offset that is provided in the string its parsing.  If it didn't work in your case, perhaps you passed something other than a string (such as a `Date` object), or a string in a non-default format - which would require the format to be specified.  Happy to help, if you want to ask a new question with your specifics. :)

Comment: @MattJohnson oh seems like I confused the answer with the jsfiddle above, which didn't use `parseZone()` but only `moment(currentTime).utcOffset()`, my apologies.

Comment: No problem. :) Thanks.