# moment.format('ZZ') returning wrong timezone offset

Tags: momentjs

I have a string `"2017-11-04T08:00:00Z"`

When I use `moment("2017-11-04T08:00:00Z").format('ZZ');` the returned string is `"+1300"` not `"Z"` as I would expect.

This becomes a problem because I am trying to build a moment date from strings of various date sections i.e  `moment(date + 'T' + time + ':00' + offset, moment.defaultFormat).format())` and passing in the wrong offset creates the completely wrong time.

Is this the incorrect usage of the format() function or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to retrieve the timezone offset as a string in this way is to use the parseZone function in conjunction with the format function as per Matt Johnson's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130440/extracting-utcoffset-from-an-iso-string-with-moment-js)

```
moment.parseZone("2017-11-04T08:00:00Z").format('Z');
```

returns...

```
"+00:00"
```

using the format function as used in the question above will return always return the users timezone offset.